# How to rotate only one image from 10 images on single page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to rotate just one image from the multiple generated images on my page. But doing so rotates all the images.
Each image is opened up in a modal and then rotated with a button.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style = "max-width:90%; max-height:90%">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body ">
            <img class="showimage img-responsive" src="" style = "max-width:90%"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" >Rotate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img').on('click', function () {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    //alert(image);
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".showimage").attr("src", image);
    });
});
});

</script>
```

This code is inside every new row inside a table
[image: Modal Representation]

[image: The different rows fetched from Directory]

Comment: There’s also a :nth-child selector in jquery, but i think you can just use smth like $(this).find(‘img’) from the button onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are loaded dynamically, here is an example of how one can achieve the rotate. To individually rotate images, I create a rotation variable that gets a reset when you click on a new cat.

```js
var rotation = 0

$('img').on('click', function () {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.showimage').attr('src', image);
    rotation = 0;
    rotate(0)
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('.rotate').on('click', function () {
      rotation += 45;
      rotate(rotation)
});

function rotate(deg) {
  $('.showimage').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)',
      '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)',
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)',
      'transform' : 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)'
  });
}
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/150" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/100" />

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style = "max-width:90%; max-height:90%">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body ">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
              <img class="showimage img-responsive" src="" style = "max-width:90%"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default rotate">Rotate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very brilliantly answered! Thanks a lot for the contribution

Answer (score 1):

The target image is identified with `.showimage` class.

But your rotate button has no class or ID. Add an identifier to that button and inject the click event to rotate the image. Add the `rotate-image` id to the button:

`<button id="rotate-image" type="button" >Rotate</button>`

And then in the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img').on('click', function () {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    //alert(image);
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      var shownImage = $(".showimage");
      shownImage.attr("src", image);

      // Remove the rotation class when modal is re-opened.
      shownImage.removeClass('rotated-image');
    });
  });

  // Add rotate event.
  $("#rotate-image").on('click', function () {
    // Add the rotation class.
    $(".showimage").addClass('rotated-image');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them  ids , if it is generated by you.

```
<img id="myimg1" src=""/>
```

this way you can do this,

```
$('img#myimg1').on('click', function () {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    //alert(image);
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".showimage").attr("src", image);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: This answer did not solve my problem :) 
I actually tried this approach before and failed. Thanks anyway